# Save image to core data while selecting image from photo album

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have used Eureka to create a form and I have installed the image framework. I have added an image row but I am struggling to save the image to coredata.

- The attribute in coredata is set to binary data
- Based on how my user form works,  I need to declare my image variable globally.

I think my problem is connecting the relationship between `NSdata` and `UIImage`. The tutorials I find handles this through `UIImagePNGRepresentation`. But they know the image file name. I don't know this as I select the file from photos.

Global variable = `var otsPhoto: NSData? = nil`

Form field

```
   <<< ImageRow() {
            $0.title = "Attachment"
            $0.sourceTypes = [.PhotoLibrary, .SavedPhotosAlbum, .Camera] //1
            $0.value = otsPhoto //2
            $0.clearAction = .yes(style: .destructive) //3
            $0.onChange { [unowned self] row in //4
                self.otsPhoto = row.value
            }
```

Returns 2 errors

> 1) cannot assign value type NSData? to type UIImage?
>
> 2) Cannot convert value of type (_) -> to expected argument

Comment: The only way to turn a UIImage into a Data without saving to a file is to use the ImageIO framework. Or, if this is already in the Photo library as an asset, ask the asset for its Data.

Comment: However, I don’t think saving an image into Core Data is wise.

Comment: I've been searching and I think I will have to come up with a new plan. What would be the best way to save images.

Comment: Why do you want to?  It’s already saved in the Photo library, isn’t it? All you need to keep is its identifier.

Comment: I looks like I have more searching and learning to do

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to store Images into Sqlite file. The best approach would be to:

1. Copy the Image from the Photos using `UIImagePickerController`
   to the application bundle or download the image from the server to
   the app bundle.
2. Get the path of the image stored from the application bundle. (you will already know this as you are storing at some location in the app bundle)
3. Store this path as a String in your table

This way even if the photo is deleted from the Photos, there is a copy of it in your app.

Some resources

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager